# Git History - Detailed Reporting

Tags: git, reporting

I am working on a report which aims to have the following:

1. Commit/Merge History - I can get these from "git log" and "git show commit-id"
2. Files changed with the specific commit - These is something I am not sure how to get

Is there a way where I can generate this via script call so I can put them in a simple text file?

Thanks!

Comment: For your (2), `git show --pretty="" --name-only <commitHash>` will output the list of files touched by said commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+changed+files+commit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git diff-tree -r --name-only <commit-hash>` to get list of modified files.